# What does the mean of identifier in Documents folder path ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this path

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D9432C44-BE6E-4079-BAD5-D8799B33023D/Documents
```

Could you please tell me what the `D9432C44-BE6E-4079-BAD5-D8799B33023D` string is? And how can I get this value by using Objective-c.
Thanks you so much.

Comment: It's the app's sandbox.  It's a randomly generated identifier that you should not care about.  It even changes during app upgrade.

Comment: Is there any module to get this value in Object C Bro?

Comment: Like I said, you shouldn’t care about it

Comment: Thanks guy. I still keep searching for this.

Comment: Why do you need it? Could you explain? Since we are telling you you shouldn't worry about it, what's the use you want with it?

Comment: Thank you guys. I just want to get it.

Comment: if you really want to get it, u get the path as string. Create array using this string separated by "/" and find that value based on the index position... that's it...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *directory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0].stringByDeletingLastPathComponent;
NSString *identifier = directory.lastPathComponent;
```